# Error para leer el driver Oracle JDBC

Tags: maven

Buen día.

Genere una clase en el IDE Eclipse-Kepler para alimentar una Base de Datos con un archivo de texto, en el proyecto maneje el driver ojdbc14 JDK 1.7 para la conexion. **Dentro de eclipse todo marcha correctamente**, pero al compilarlo con Maven y ejecutar el .jar me envía el siguiente error:

"No suitable driver found for jdbc:oracle:thin:@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxxx:BDNAME
Error de lectura del archivojava.lang.NullPointerException."

Ocupo una clase para la conexión:

```
public class DespachadorBD {

    public static final String DB_DRIVER = "oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver";
    public static final String DB_CONNECTION = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@192.xxx.xxx.xxx:XXXX:DBNAME";
    public static final String DB_USER = "User";
    public static final String DB_PASSWORD = "Pass";    
}
...
...

private static Connection getDBConnection() {

                Connection dbConnection = null;
                try {
                    Class.forName(DB_DRIVER);
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
                }
                try {
                    dbConnection = DriverManager.getConnection(
                                    DB_CONNECTION, DB_USER,DB_PASSWORD);
                    return dbConnection;
                } catch (SQLException e) {
                    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
                }
                return dbConnection;
            }
}
```

De antemano agradezco su apoyo y comentarios.
Saludos.

Comment: **[Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en Español](http://es.stackoverflow.com/tour)**. Puedes consultar aquí [qué funciones tiene Stack Overflow en Español para que puedas organizar el código o lo que coloques en tus preguntas y/o respuestas](http://meta.es.stackoverflow.com/a/1453/78). Saludos. Por curiosidad, ¿has buscado en internet si alguien mas tiene este error?

Answer (score 1):

Estuve buscando por otro lado y pude resolver el conflicto de la excepción del `Driver Oracle JDBC`.

Comparto la liga que me ayudo con el problema, hice unas correcciones y aditamentos para mi clase y también les comparto otra liga con la teoría.

El conflicto tiene que ver con el `ClassLoader` y puedes revisar la teoría [aquí](https://www.arquitecturajava.com/el-concepto-de-classloader/) y el método que ocupé para cargar ojdbc puedes revisarlo en la [liga](http://chuwiki.chuidiang.org/index.php?title=Cambiar_el_classpath_en_tiempo_de_ejecuci%C3%B3n).

Por último les comparto la clase que ocupe adaptándolo en un método y mandarlo a llamar donde sea necesario.

```
package com;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLClassLoader;
import java.sql.SQLException;

public class PruebaCambioClassPath {

    public void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            driver();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }


    }

    public void driver() throws SQLException {

        // Comprobamos que en el classpath no existe el driver de mysql.
        try {
            Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("no se encuentra com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        }

        // Cambiamos el classpath, anadiendo un nuevo jar al ClassLoader.
        try {
            // Se obtiene el ClassLoader y su metodo addURL()
            URLClassLoader classLoader = ((URLClassLoader) ClassLoader
                    .getSystemClassLoader());
            Method metodoAdd = URLClassLoader.class.getDeclaredMethod("addURL",
                    new Class[] { URL.class });
            metodoAdd.setAccessible(true);

            // La URL del jar que queremos anadir
            URL url = new URL(
                    "file:///C:/Users/Usuario/.m2/repository/com/oracle/10.2.0.5.0/oracle-10.2.0.5.0.jar");

            // Se invoca al metodo addURL pasando esa url del jar
            metodoAdd.invoke(classLoader, new Object[] { url });
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        // Se comprueba que ahora si se puede acceder a esa clase.
        try {
            Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
            System.out.println("ya se encuentra com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("Pues no, sigue sin estar accesible");
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Recuerda [aceptar tu propia respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer). Saludos.